# Cancellation points in signal handlers?

Tags: c, pthreads, posix, signals, cancellation

What happens if a program calls a function which is a cancellation point from a signal handler? There are a number of functions which POSIX specifies as both async-signal-safe and cancellation points. If a signal handler calls such a function and cancellation is acted upon, the result is quite similar to what would happen if the thread had enabled asynchronous cancellation - actually much worse, because all the cancellation cleanup handlers, which are probably not async-signal-safe, would be called from a signal-handler context.

What does POSIX actually specify in this case, and what do implementations actually do? I can't find any language in POSIX that would forbid cancellation points in signal handlers from being acted upon, nor any such protection in the glibc/nptl source.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not aware that POSIX even dares to mention this topic, but I haven't done an exhaustive search.

Some brief experimentation with a gcc/nptl system reveals that, as I suspected and I think you did too, there is no such protection in NPTL - the cancellation handlers do indeed get called, from within the signal handler context.

The program below (apologies for the hackiness etc) displays the following output:

```
Signal handler called
Sent cancellation
Cleanup called
In sighandler
```

... indicating that:

- the signal handler got called
- the other thread then called `pthread_cancel()`
- the cancellation handler then got called, without the signal handler completing

Here's the program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <assert.h>

pthread_t mainthread;

int in_sighandler = 0;

void
cleanup (void *arg)
{
    write(1, "Cleanup called\n", strlen("Cleanup called\n"));
    if (in_sighandler) {
        write(1, "In sighandler\n", strlen("In sighandler\n"));
    } else {
        write(1, "Not in sighandler\n", strlen("In sighandler\n"));
    }
}


void
sighandler (int sig, siginfo_t *siginfo, void *arg)
{
    in_sighandler = 1;
    write(1,"Signal handler called\n", strlen("Signal handler called\n"));  // write() is a CP
    usleep(3000000); // usleep() is a CP; not strictly async-signal-safe but happens to be so in Linux
    write(1, "Signal handler exit\n", strlen("Signal handler exit\n"));
    in_sighandler = 0;
}

void *
thread (void *arg)
{
    sleep(1);
    pthread_kill(mainthread, SIGUSR1);
    usleep(500000);
    pthread_cancel(mainthread);
    printf("Sent cancellation\n");
    return (NULL);
}

int
main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    int rc;
    struct sigaction sa;
    pthread_t threadid;

    mainthread = pthread_self();

    // Set up a signal handler to test its cancellation properties
    sa.sa_sigaction = &sighandler;
    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
    sa.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
    rc = sigaction(SIGUSR1, &sa, NULL);
    assert(rc == 0);

    // Set up a thread to send us signals and cancel us
    rc = pthread_create(&threadid, NULL, &thread, NULL);
    assert(rc == 0);

    // Set up cleanup handlers and loop forever
    pthread_cleanup_push(&cleanup, NULL);
    while (1) {
        sleep(60);
    }
    pthread_cleanup_pop(0);
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: Short of any better answer coming in soon, I'll probably accept yours. As far as I can tell, this basically just means you can't use cancellation in a program unless your signal handlers disable cancellation themselves or avoid calling any function that may be a cancellation point. This in turn, unfortunately, means that library code utilizing threads without the calling program's awareness/cooperation cannot use cancellation at all (because the calling program might have setup signal handlers); any use could result in race conditions where the signal handler gets cancelled.

Comment: Yep,that's right - though strictly speaking the signal handler can't disable cancellation (the pthread functions aren't async-signal-safe). The library *could* block *all* signals in any threads it creates, but that's not ideal (especially since blocking SIGRTMIN on Linux disables cancellation...). I've always thought cancellation was dangerous - you can't call any library functions from a cancellable thread unless you're certain the library was designed with cancellation in mind (or else it might allocate resources, call a cancellation point function, then never free those resources...)

Comment: For what it's worth I've just tried the same program on a machine running Solaris 10, with the same results... I guess that means that, even if there does turn out to be something in the standard making this safe, it's useless since the most common implementations don't support it :-/

Comment: Your comment about blocking all signals solves the problem, I think. Blocking signals via `pthread_sigmask` is not allowed to block cancellation. If cancellation is implemented through signals, that must be transparent to the application, and in practice (at least on glibc/nptl), the `pthread_sigmask` library function (and the `sigprocmask` function which is not required to be safe at all in threaded applications) silently refuses to mask `SIGCANCEL` and `SIGSETXID` (both used internally by the implementation).

Comment: Thus, a library wishing to use threads and cancellation internally without the cooperation of the calling application simply needs to use `pthread_sigmask` to block all signals before calling `pthread_create`, and must restore the original signal mask sometime between then and returning to the caller. If using cancellation, it should also explicitly disable cancellation whenever calling external library code that might not be cancellation-aware.